# Retrieving the ProductCodes of instance transforms defined inside of an MSI with C#

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, instance-transform

I have a set of InstanceTransforms defined on the WiX side, as per below:

```
<InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
  <Instance ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" ProductName="ProductName $(var.VersionText) (64 bit)" Id="$(var.InstanceId)"/>
  <Instance ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode1)" ProductName="ProductName $(var.VersionText) (64 bit)" Id="$(var.InstanceId1)"/>
  <Instance ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode2)" ProductName="ProductName $(var.VersionText) (64 bit)" Id="$(var.InstanceId2)"/>
  <Instance ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode3)" ProductName="ProductName $(var.VersionText) (64 bit)" Id="$(var.InstanceId3)"/>
  <Instance ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode4)" ProductName="ProductName $(var.VersionText) (64 bit)" Id="$(var.InstanceId4)"/>
</InstanceTransforms>
```

I would like to retrieved the **ProductCodes** of the **instance transforms** through my bootstrapper which is a C# windows application that evokes the .msi. Since those ProductCodes are generated dynamically during the installer's build, I thought I would have to query the msi using the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller assembly. However, in examining the .msi with ORCA, I can't seem to find a table that would allow me to query for the ProductCodes of the instance transforms. The property table just has the ProductCode of the Product element.

Is it possible to retrieve the ProductCodes of the instance transforms? When I attempt a same version upgrade with the same installer, I do see the ProductCode corresponding to the InstanceTransform in the .msi's error log:

> Specified instance {8F97345E-DDAD-4F03-9D17-820E929C59FE} via
>   transform  is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new
>   instance that is not installed.

If someone could help me out with this one, that'd be great - thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I suspect you'd need to know the name and location of the actual transform files, the .mst files. Then you'd do the equivalent of MsiOpenDatabase() followed by MsiDatabaseApplyTransform, then do the SQL query on the Property table to get the ProductCode.

Comment: Hiya Phil, thanks a lot for your reply - I am evoking my instance transform through the following properties: INSTANCEID=INSTANCEID1 MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=\":INSTANCE_TRANSFORM1\". Because I am not explicitly referring an .mst file, I thought that my transforms would be embedded in the .msi itself and not externally located. In that case, would I need to call MsiOpenDatabase() on the .msi file itself and query the _Storage table first?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it(using bootstrapper).I just check for the next available instance for transform . You can check in the registry for the keys and get the next available:

```
   public static string[] CheckRegKeys(Product product)
    {
        var productEnvironment = MapProductToString.MapProductEnvironment(product);
        var productKeys = new string[50];

        for (var i = 0; i < productKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < 9)
            {
                productKeys[i] = string.Format("{0}#0{1}", productEnvironment, i + 1);
                continue;
            }

            productKeys[i] = string.Format("{0}#{1}", productEnvironment, i + 1);
        }

        return productKeys;
    }

    public static string FindNextEnvironmentForInstallation(Product product)
    {
        var productName = MapProductToString.MapProductToRegistryName(product);
        var productKeys = CheckRegKeys(product);
        using (var componentsKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"Software\Wow6432Node\{0}", productName), false))
        {
            if (componentsKey == null)
            {
                Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(string.Format(@"Software\Wow6432Node\{0}", productName));
                return string.Format("I0{0}", 1);
            }

            var environments = componentsKey.GetSubKeyNames();
            if (environments.Length <= 0)
            {
                var result = string.Format("I0{0}", 1);
                return result;

            }
            for (var i = 0; i < productKeys.Length; i++)
            {
                if (environments.Length < i + 1)
                {
                    if (i < 9)
                    {
                        var result = string.Format("I0{0}", i + 1);
                        return result;
                    }

                    var result2 = string.Format("I{0}", i + 1);
                    return result2;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Next you send the value to the msi :

```
 using (var p = new Process())
                {
                    var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = string.Format("/c msiexec /i \"{0}\\{6}.msi\" PATHNAME=\"{0}\" SSLCERTPATH=\"{1}\"" +
                        " MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=\":{2}\" /L*v \"{0}\\{6}Log.txt\""
                        , XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPath, environment),
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    };
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ProductCode is the name of the registry key container for that particular installation. These are found here:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

So you could write a Custom Action to scan the registry contents to determine the correct base key.

I actually write a lot of special instance information into this install key during installation using something like this:

```
<Component Id="cmpMIValues" Permanent="no" Guid="YOUR-GUID-HERE" Win64 ="yes" Directory ="TARGETDIR" MultiInstance="yes" >
  <Condition><![CDATA[TRANSFORMS]]></Condition>
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode]" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ProductCode" Value="[ProductCode]" KeyPath="no" />
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="UpgradeCode" Value="[UpgradeCode]" KeyPath="no" />
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallTime" Value="[INSTALLTIME]" KeyPath="no" />
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstanceId" Value="[INSTANCEID]" KeyPath="no" />
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstanceName" Value="[INSTANCENAME]" KeyPath="no" />
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

(Some of the above variables are created by a custom action.)

Your other alternative would be to simply used fixed GUIDs instead of the '*'. Then you could use a lookup table in a custom action to determine the correct GUID for a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using random guids just generate guids by InstanceIds. Here is an example:

```
    public static Guid GenerateGuidByString(string input)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            var hashBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(hashBytes);
            return new Guid(hash);
        }
    }
```